# StreamBuilder using StreamController from Firestore snapshots

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, stream, google-cloud-firestore

I am try load Firestore snapshots() into StreamController so can give to StreamBuilder so can build newsfeed in app.

But get error:

> The getter 'stream' was called on null.
>
> The method 'add' was called on
>   null.

Here my code:

```
StreamController<QuerySnapshot> _localStreamController = StreamController<QuerySnapshot>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

Firestore.instance.collection(‘info’).snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {

//      if(userAdded == null) {
        _localStreamController.add(querySnapshot);
//      }

    });
...
child: StreamBuilder(
stream: _localStreamController.stream,
builder: (context, snapshot) {
```

Anyone know solution?
Thanks!

Comment: why don't directly use - `stream: Firestore.instance.collection(‘info’).snapshots()`

Comment: @anmol.majhail Thanks for reply! Cannot use direct because this will cause rebuild on every new event. I find this also cause issue with `Navigator.push` because `Navigator.push` may be call while `StreamBuilder` is rebuild. So cause Widget tree issue

Comment: `Streams` are for that purpose - to perform action on each events. Use `future`  instead of stream. if you want to get data once.

Comment: @anmol.majhail I want stream and automatic get new data. But if user tap must then cancel stream to navigate

Answer (score 1):

**Solution #1 :**

You need to initialize the stream Replace this line

```
StreamController<QuerySnapshot> _localStreamController = StreamController<QuerySnapshot>();
```

with:

```
StreamController<QuerySnapshot> _localStreamController = StreamController.broadcast();
```

because `broadcast()` need to listen to data before requesting it from firebase you need to add listener in the `initSatat` it will be some thing like this :

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    // this doesn't have to do any thing  
    _localStreamController.stream.listen((event)=>print(event));
    Firestore.instance.collection('info').snapshots().listen((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) =>
    _localStreamController.add(querySnapshot));
    super.initState();

  }
```

and your stream builder look like this :

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: _localStreamController.stream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ...
    } else {
     return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
)
```

**Solution #2 :**

you can loss the controller and stream the data directly in the Stream builder all throw it's not best practice.
it will be some thing like this:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('info').snapshots(), // <= change
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return ...
    } else {
     return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  },
)
```

and you don't to use `StreamController` or `initState`

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the stream
Replace this line:

```
StreamController<QuerySnapshot> _localStreamController = StreamController<QuerySnapshot>();
```

with:

```
StreamController<QuerySnapshot> _localStreamController = StreamController.broadcast();
```

Then in your builder, you will want to account for the data not being loaded yet. So showing a loading screen or something could be useful. Something like this:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data.documents.length == 0) {
            return Center(child: const Text('Loading ...'));
          }
```

Comment: how can we define it in null safety? Thanks.